# Pointer to member function weirdness

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to do some binding with my C++ code, and use pointer to member functions.

I have the following code :

```
class A
{
explicit A(float);
}
class B
{
void setA(A);
void setA(float);
}
```

Then I declare the pointer to member functions :

```
(void (B::*)(A))&B::setA
(void (B::*)(float))&B::setA
```

The compiler (MSVC11) finds the second line is ambiguous.

If I comment setA(A) in class B, both lines are considered ok by the compiler (!)

Is it a compiler bug?

Is there a way to circumvent that, without modifying class B's signature?

EDIT :

Actually, the code I posted was oversimplified from my real classes and did compile..

Here's a modified version that really reproduces the bug :

```
class A
{
public:
    explicit A(float f=1.0f, float g=1.0f) {}
};
class B
{
public:
    void setA(A){}
    void setA(float f, float g=1.0f){}
};
```

with

```
(void (B::*)(A))&B::setA
(void (B::*)(float))&B::setA
(void (B::*)(float,float))&B::setA
```

The 2nd line brings a compile error :
error C2440: 'type casting' : impossible to convert 'overloaded-function' to 'void (__thiscall B::* )(float)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this is a bug. Per Paragraph 13.4/1 of the C++11 Standard:

> A use of an overloaded function name without arguments is resolved in certain contexts to a function, a
>   pointer to function or a **pointer to member function** for a specific function from the overload set. [...] . **The function selected
>   is the one whose type is *identical* to the function type of the target type required in the context**. [...] The target can be
>
> — an object or reference being initialized (8.5, 8.5.3),
>
> — the left side of an assignment (5.17),
>
> — a parameter of a function (5.2.2),
>
> — a parameter of a user-defined operator (13.5),
>
> — the return value of a function, operator function, or conversion (6.6.3),
>
> — **an explicit type conversion** (5.2.3, 5.2.9, 5.4), or
>
> — a non-type template-parameter (14.3.2).

Since it is pretty clear which member function from the overload set has a signature identical to the one you are explicitly casting it to, your code is legal.

Besides, your code compiles fine with Clang 3.2, GCC 4.7.2, GCC 4.8, ICC 13.0.1 and (!) VC10. See, for instance, [this live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3kW04t%24167).

**EDIT:**

The new code you posted is indeed illegal.

The second cast cannot be resolved, because none of the member functions `setA()` takes only *one* float parameter. Therefore, the compiler doesn't know which function you mean by the expression `&B::setA`. Normally, it would try to disambiguate based on the contextual explicit conversion, but that doesn't help, because it specifies a signature which is incompatible with the signature of both overloads of `setA()`.

If you are wondering why this is the case and why the second overload is not picked, then the reason is that a parameter with a default argument is still a formal parameter of your function (even if it could be omitted in some calls), and its type still counts as part of the function's signature.

Default arguments, on the other hand, are not part of a function's signature:

> **1.3.20 [defns.signature.member]**
>
> **signature**
>
> `<class member function>` name, parameter type list (8.3.5), class of which the function is a member, *cv*-qualifiers (if any), and *ref-qualifier* (if any)

Now if you remove the overload `setA(A)`, the compiler *does* know what member function the expression `&B::setA` refers to, because there is only one. No need to use the explicit cast in order to resolve the expression.

Then, since function pointers can be cast to function pointers of other types, the compiler performs an additional conversion to the specified target type.

Comment: Ok, but then, why does the code compiles if setA(A) does not exist? Is it the compiler being too liberal?

Comment: @Mikarnage: Oh, it seems I have been too superficial. I will try to correct the answer. Sorry about that

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! For the context, I was trying to use luabind, and it doesn't detect default args by itself.

Comment: @Mikarnage: Unfortunately I do not know Lua, so I can't help with that. But good luck with your project ;)